# Explanation of head to tail method in physical quantities interaction

Tags: electromagnetism

When we add vector A and B by parallelogram method ,we can think it as the two quantities acting "on the common point of" their tails and the net/resultant effect on that point those quantities. But what about Head-to-tail method ? What will be physical explanation for this ?

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191090/37364) doesn't answer your question, but it may give you some insight into what physicists mean by a vector.

Comment: The meaning is that one is applied after the other (where "after" is by logic, not by time).

Comment: But head to tail method work for all vectors even when multiple vectors are working on a point simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The parallelogram and tip to tail methods are really the same thing. If you put A at the origin and B at A's tip, you get two sides of a parallelogram. If you do it the other way around, B at the origin then A, you get the other two sides.

---

Edited to respond to comments

Little arrows are not a trick. They are a tool that is so useful people think of all vectors as little arrows. Coordinates are another such tool.

First, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191090/37364) for what a vector really is. (TLDR: Vectors are things that add like little arrows. But they can be very different from little arrows.)

Small displacements are one type of vector. If $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are two displacements, $\vec{A} +\vec{B}$ is the total displacement you get from displacement $\vec{A}$ followed by displacement $\vec{B}$. It is easy to see how how little arrows laid tip to tail generate this displacement.

For  this case, it makes sense to question whether tip to tail or parallelogram addition more closely represents the physical situation. It turns out both work equally well.

Forces are another type of vector. Force is like a little arrow in that it has a magnitude and a direction. But force is not a little arrow. Force is something that produces acceleration when applied to an object. You can calculate the acceleration from $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$.

Forces add when two or more are simultaneously applied to an object. For example, the floor may push up on an object at the same time as gravity pulls it down. In this case

$$\vec{F_{total}} = \vec{F_{floor}} + \vec{F_{gravity}}$$

The acceleration is calculated from the sum of the forces. That is the physics of adding forces.

$$\vec{F_{total}} = m \vec{a}$$

In this case, $\vec{F_{floor}} + \vec{F_{gravity}}$ are equal and opposite. So $\vec{F_{total}} = \vec{0}$. The object is not accelerated.

All vectors add like little arrows. Little arrows are a tool that can help you add vectors such as forces. Little arrow tip to tail addition or parallelogram addition work equally well.

It is important to realize that you are not adding forces tip to tail. Forces do not come one after the other. Forces are applied to the same object.

Comment: Yes sir absolutely ....so it is a trick only to represent in different way ? I mean if we talk about displacement vector is can be used and physical explanation can be seen there but  is there any general physical explanation to the head to tail method

Comment: @NandaSinha If you have position vector $\vec{r_i}$ and you displace through $\vec{d}$, then try finding $\vec{r_f}$ using your head-tail method :) ($\vec{r_f} = \vec{r_i} + \vec{d}$)

Comment: Force is a vector, but force is not a little arrow. Force is like a little arrow in some ways. Little arrows are one type of vector, but there are many others. The physical interpretation of tip to tail addition of little arrows vs parallelogram addition may not tell you anything about force.

Comment: This is merely anecdotal, but I remember not being at all happy about adding forces by the parallelogram rule, when first introduced to it. When I started using the 'head-to-tail' method I felt a lot happier, because this is self-evidently the way that $displacements$ add. I was comfortable with the idea that a force was the same kind of object of object as a displacement.

Comment: So should I take it as a trick to feel comfortable ?... Is it a trick  to give a feel of similarness with displacement vector? So no physical interpretation ? ( asking politely )

Comment: Like messier314 (see excellent answer above) I deprecate the term "trick". Adding like little arrows (or alternatively, as messer hints, by cartesian components) is a very important property that Euclidian vector quantities have in common. It's not difficult to see why this should be so, as velocity is defined in terms of displacement, acceleration and momentum in terms of velocity, force in terms of momentum.